# Creating gap in date/time for scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my first time posting for help, so my apologies if my formatting isn't the best.

I am working with movement data, and I am trying to plot the distance between a detection coordinate (variable) and the original release location (fixed). I am trying to make a scatter plot with the x axis = time (or date, I don't really care), and the y axis = distance. I am struggling to create gaps in the x axis...

Below is my df:

```
df = structure(list(runID = c(498566070L, 509356752L, 536916154L, 
506389550L, 537067337L, 536916204L, 536916207L), batchID = c(9830063L, 
10155801L, 10938151L, 10016748L, 10961363L, 10938151L, 10938151L
), ts = c(1679273215.2957, 1679318323.7441, 1680044684.1054, 
1680098442.0468, 1680208319.415, 1680556238.2234, 1680611995.7129
), sig = c(-71.3499, -68.6303, -70.3385, -75.7641, -70.2695, 
-69.5032, -64.8839), motusTagID = c(72222L, 72222L, 72222L, 72222L, 
72222L, 72222L, 72222L), mfgID = c(34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
34L), tagDeployID = c(44517L, 44517L, 44517L, 44517L, 44517L, 
44517L, 44517L), deployDay = c("2023-01-30 21:10:00", "2023-01-30 21:10:00", 
"2023-01-30 21:10:00", "2023-01-30 21:10:00", "2023-01-30 21:10:00", 
"2023-01-30 21:10:00", "2023-01-30 21:10:00"), time = c("2023-03-20 00:46:55.2957", 
"2023-03-20 13:18:43.7441", "2023-03-28 23:04:44.1054", "2023-03-29 14:00:42.0468", 
"2023-03-30 20:31:59.415", "2023-04-03 21:10:38.2234", "2023-04-04 12:39:55.7129"
), Latitude = c(42.3787, 42.9254, 44.2852, 44.2082, 43.6489, 
44.2852, 44.2852), Longitude = c(-82.3998, -81.3673, -81.1, -80.6122, 
-81.4697, -81.1, -81.1), recvDeployID = c(8543L, 8193L, 9403L, 
9140L, 9375L, 9403L, 9403L), recvDeployName = c("St.Clair NWA", 
"Auzins", "Chesley", "Priceville", "Hullet Provincial Wildlife Area", 
"Chesley", "Chesley"), month = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), 
    date = c("2023-03-20", "2023-03-21", "2023-03-29", "2023-03-30", 
    "2023-03-31", "2023-04-04", "2023-04-05"), season = c("Winter", 
    "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Migration", "Migration"
    ), distance = c(74136.1949157258, 115256.803099234, 37649.3976711614, 
    54318.7176093354, 95946.5000323143, 42530.6634270511, 0), 
    bearing = c(182.768358871665, 4.26954886316531, 37.7847084726575, 
    358.563380769542, 185.795437830525, 14.6144437561853, NA), 
    cardinal = c("S", "N", "NE", "N", "S", "N", NA), Treatment = c("Fergus Long Displacement", 
    "Fergus Long Displacement", "Fergus Long Displacement", "Fergus Long Displacement", 
    "Fergus Long Displacement", "Fergus Long Displacement", "Fergus Long Displacement"
    ), ReleaseLat = c(42.24372, 42.24372, 42.24372, 42.24372, 
    42.24372, 42.24372, 42.24372), ReleaseLon = c(-82.76708, 
    -82.76708, -82.76708, -82.76708, -82.76708, -82.76708, -82.76708
    ), DistFromRelease = c(40931.3748009449, 156171.624875343, 
    188269.475488752, 241918.902014031, 145997.182876024, 188269.475488752, 
    188269.475488752)), row.names = 9:15, class = "data.frame")
```

Below is the code I am running to create a plot:

```
ggplot(df |> filter(mfgID == 34), aes(x=date, y=DistFromRelease)) + 
  geom_point(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

I have attached a photo of the plot this creates. The problem is that I want gaps between days... for example, you can see that between March 21 and March 29, there is no gap to include the missing dates.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ld34.png)

Any advice is greatly appreciated!!! Thank you:)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your `date` column is a character. Instead, try with converting to a proper date, i.e. do `x = as.Date(date)`.

Comment: R doesn't know your date strings are supposed to represent dates, so it is creating a categorical x axis, much as it would if the `date` column contained "Apple", "banana", "pear" etc . You need to convert the date strings into actual dates.  Try `df$date <- as.Date(df$date)` and run your code again.

Comment: Thank you Stefan and Allan, you've saved me!! Much appreciated:) Cheers!